# SQL Infinite loading

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb, infinite-loop

I have a database with 1 million records, it's working fine with around to 1.2s response time for simple queries using *JOIN, GROUP BY, ORDER*, .. It's ok and there are no problems with that. I'm working to simplify my queries using table aliases, but when I execute a simple query with two table aliases or more, the request never ends and MariaDB doesn't respond anymore, I have to restart the service manually.

Whats is going wrong ?

**Here it's structure:**

```
CREATE TABLE `values` (
  `id` mediumint(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `date` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `indexVar` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `value` float NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Data:
[exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUC2o.png)

**Working query:**

```
SELECT
    v.date,
    v.value
FROM
    `values` AS v
WHERE
    v.date > 1548460800 AND v.indexVar = 6 OR v.indexVar = 2
```

[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDI01.png)

**Infinite loading query:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    v.date,
    v1.value,
    v2.value
FROM
    `values` AS v,
    `values` AS v1,
    `values` AS v2
WHERE
    v.date > 1548460800 AND v1.indexVar = 6 AND v2.indexVar = 2
```

[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irEha.png)

Comment: why you use the second query?  .. join 3 1M rows tables  can produce lower performance  ..   looking tor your FROM (and where) clause  your are selecting a cartesian product between 3 table of 1M rows  1M*1M*1M .... ..???   ..

Comment: I need to align multiple values in the same row based on the date

Comment: Update your question add  a clear data sample and the expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't including any join conditions in your query.

If the values table has 1 million rows, then including it twice gives you a result set with 1 million * 1 million = 1 trillion rows. You are applying some conditions, but you're still going to wind up with a huge number of results. (And you're including the values table three times!)

Let's say you have a table with a million rows, and each row is just an integer from 1 to 1 million. If you do `select value from values where value > 900000` then you'll get 100,000 rows. But if you say `select value from values v, values v2 where v.value > 900000` then for each of 100,000 rows matched by the `v.value > 900000` condition you'll get all million rows from v2. Even if you apply the same filter to v2 (i.e., `v2.value > 900000`) the query will still return 100,000 v2 rows for each row in the original values table--10 billion rows in all.

If `date` is the primary key of the table, then you must make sure that all the `date` values in each result row are the same:

```
select v.date, v1.value, v2.value
from values v, values v1, values v2
where v.date = v1.date and v.date = v2.date
and v1.indexVar = 6 and v2.indexVar = 2
```

or better yet:

```
select v.date, v1.value, v2.value
from values v
    inner join values v1 on (v1.date = v.date)
    inner join values v2 on (v2.date = v.date)
where v1.indexVar = 6 and v2.indexVar = 2
```

If the primary key is `id` then just do the same with `id`. (You said you wanted to align rows based on the date, so not sure which column is most significant.)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a fake aggregation function and group for reduce the result of a  case  when for filter

```
SELECT date
   , max(case when v.indexVar = 6 then v.values end) v1_value
   , max(case when v.indexVar = 2  then v.values end) v2_value 

FROM   values 
WHERE
    date > 1548460800 AND indexVar = 6 OR indexVar = 2 
group by date
```

you should also add  a proper composite index

```
create index  idx1 on values ( indexVar, date)
```